# change slds-select icon

Tags: lightning, css, lightning-design-system, selectlist

I want to change the icon on the right of a slds-select. the default looks like this:

[image: default].

But I would like mine to look like this:

[image].

This is my code:

```
<lightning:select aura:id="title" value="{!v.Title__c}" class="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input--bare slds-has-divider--bottom "  name="title" label="{!v.labels.title__c+' *'}" onchange="{!c.onChange}">
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.titlePicklistValues}" var="plv">
  <option value="{!plv.value}" text="{!plv.label}" selected="{!(v.Title__c==plv.value?'true':'false')}"></option>
 </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

How do I change that selector on the right that triggers the dropdown?

Comment: Have you any client-side controller? If yes, then post it here and also refer this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the SLDS CSS. This won't be the exact down arrow you have. You'll need more for that.

```
.THIS .slds-select_container::before { border-bottom: none;}
.THIS .slds-select_container::after { border-top: none;}
.THIS .slds-select_container .slds-select { -webkit-appearance : menuList}
```

Answer (score 0):

.THIS .slds-select_container:before{

```
border-bottom: 0px!important;
```

}

Use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
.THIS .slds-select_container::before { border-bottom: none;}
.THIS .slds-select_container::after { border-top: none;}
.THIS .slds-select_container .slds-select{
    width:100%;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: transparent url("your png") no-repeat right;
}
```

This works fine for me.`-webkit-appearance` not supported in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

```
.THIS .slds-select_container:after {
    border-top: 5px solid rgb(6, 28, 63);
    bottom: calc((1.75rem / 2) - 2px);
}
```